# Server dropping all clients at intervals

Tags: networking, php, hosting

I administrate large-scale servers for Minecraft: Pocket Edition. For the past couple of months, I have had the issue where at intervals the server will close all active connections to it (VNC and in-game) and go offline for a period of about 30 seconds, after which it comes back online. This happens once every 20 minutes or so. The server has an average load of 3.1 MB upload and 600kb download, powering 57 players, and using 40%.CPU on all four cores. The problem scales, with fewer players and server instances running simultaneously, the disconnects stop happeniing, and with more players and server instances, the problems increase. The server is being powered off of a godaddy dedicated server, which promises at least 10mb throughput, so it should not be causing a problem. I am using thier $140 dedicated server, running centos. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There isn't much to go on here yet.  You can revise your question with software versions, logs, stats before, during, after the server goes offline, etc.  Does the server actually go offline or just Minecraft?  If it is a paid server with GoDaddy why not contact them directly for assistance?

Comment: Could you confirm that you are running Pocket Edition servers? I was under the impression that PE was peer-to-peer.

Comment: I am. I am using the software pocketmine (pocketnine.net). All I have in the way of logs is a lot of players timing out at the same time.

Comment: The server actually goes offline, otherwise VNC would not disconnect. Godaddy blamed thorughput, but I'm never using more then 3.2mb/10.

Comment: In that case, I'd ask GoDaddy support to escalate the ticket. I would even consider a different host (ideally, a smaller, local one, which would typically have better support).

Comment: Seconded: GoDaddy has not, in my experience, been competent at dedicated servers.

Comment: OK, thanks, even though I don't think I can change IPs without causing some major problems.